# How much is/are there?

Tags: phrase-choice

I got confused with this kind of questions
Do I have to say: **How many apples are in the fridge?** Or **How many apples are there in the fridge?**
Is there any difference? It's because I've seen both type and I don't know which one I should use.
It would be amazing if someone helps me.

Comment: They're both totally natural.

Comment: Ohhh, so are both of them correct?

Comment: Yep, they're both fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many people are (there) in your family?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192476/how-many-people-are-there-in-your-family)